# How to remove data inserted in the application in the core data

Tags: ios, sql, core-data, ios6, ios7

In Core data , I have prepopulated some data using command line application of Mac.

After that in the application I am storing some additional data .Now the problem is whenever the application terminates the data which is not pre populated and I have stored is still there . I want it to be removed [the data which is added in application only not the prepopulated data] .

can anyone suggest me how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't want to ever store data created inside of the application but you always want to revert to the preloaded data.  If this is not correct please clarify by updating your question.

If that is correct then what I would do is add a second `NSPersistentStore` to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  The second one would be of type "In Memory".  Further, I would change the options on the first store to be read-only.

With these changes the users will add objects and they will go into the in-memory store.  When the application quits the in memory store is released and the changes go away.

Comment: you are right Marcus , I think I'll have to revisit my thought process .. If I want to do this .. then why should I use core data ?? I can always do this in simple array dictionary setup right ?

Comment: And lose all of the model, searching and structure that Core Data provides, sure.